# Fixed navbar breaks up and covers content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

When I try to scroll with my fixed navbar code the bar breaks up into only the boxes for the links and it covers the page title, how do I fix this? All my code is in a pastebin as it would have been too long to post directly on here.

http://pastebin.com/CBvGcKT4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be to push padding-top to the body.
The nav block is fixed, so it doesn't 'physically' interfere with anything, which means it will not push your content below it.

I see you are using jQuery, so we can use it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var navHeight = $('#nav').height();
        $('body').css("padding-top", navHeight);
    });
</script>
```

Getting the height and passing it trought the body's padding-top everytime after page load, is a fail-safe solution, so if your menu elements are more and the menu has two or more rows of them, the content will follow right after.

For this solution to work properly you need to remove the fixed heights you put in:

```
#nav, .fixed-nav-bar {
    height: auto;
}
```

and let them do the magic themselves.

Answer (score 0):

First you should fix your code.
You set `h1` and `nav` inside `head` tag and that is wrong, it should go inside `body`.
To check what elements go inside head tag visit this page: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_head.asp

So after you put that code inside body check bootstrap documentation as it already have class for [fixed navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top) and here you write your own.

Then I suggest to put h1 title below navbar, not above as it is now, so that code matches visual placement of elements.
And also, like it is said on bootstrap documentation for fixed top navbar, you should add `padding-top` to your body if you use `.navbar-fixed-top`.
By default navbar is 50px high but because you increased it then add more `padding-top` to body.

Also your links look like this:

```
<li><a href="What Are Drones.html">What Are Drones</a></li>
```

In most cases this will not work so you should remove spaces from html file name.
 Like this for example:

```
<li><a href="what-are-drones.html">What Are Drones</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This code will perfectly work for you.**
 *Happy Coding :-)*

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
#TITLE {color: #1762a1; font-family: "Cuprum", sans-serif; font-size:80px;}

.navbar-nav li a{color: white ! important; font-family: "Cuprum", sans-serif; }
.navbar-brand{color: white ! important;}

BODY{PADDING-TOP: 50px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Drones</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="btt index.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="indexCSS.css" />

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Kittatinny's Drone Information</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="What Are Drones.html">What Are Drones</a></li>
    <li><a href="How Drones Work.html">How Drones Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="Buying a Drone.html">Buying a Drone</a></li>
    <li><a href="About Us.html">About Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  <h1 id="TITLE" class="text-center"> Kittatinny's Drone Information</h1>
</head>
```